# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alt' of null :Script stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

when i get error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alt' of null , my script works fine in browser but sometimes i see dragged object gets stucked when i inspect via device inscept i see belwo error

my script stops executing how can i prevent that ??..

see http://liveweave.com/GknZjq

```
(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');

    var group;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
        var img1 = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
            var img2 = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            group = new fabric.Group([img1, img2], {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            canvas.add(group)
        });
    });


    fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
        var img1 = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
            var img2 = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            group1 = new fabric.Group([img1, img2], {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            canvas1.add(group1)
        });
    });



    $(document).ready(function () {



        /* Define drag and drop zones */
        var $drop = $('#canvas-drop-area,#canvas-drop-area1'),
            $gallery = $('td > #image-list li'),
            $draggedImage=null;

        /* Define the draggable properties */
        $gallery.draggable({
             helper: 'clone',
            start: function (e) {
            $draggedImage=event.target;
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                })
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).find('img').css({
                   /* 'opacity': 0.4 */
                });
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
                $draggedImage=null;
            },
            revert: true
        });

        /* Define the events for droppable properties */
        $drop.droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var image =$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src;
                console.log($draggedImage.alt);
                img_to_canvas(image,$draggedImage.alt,$(event.target).is("#canvas-drop-area")?1:2);
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            },
            deactivate: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });

    });


    var img_to_canvas = function(image,sendfront,checkcanvas) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image;
        if(checkcanvas =='1'){
            if(sendfront=='top'){
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group.item(0).setElement(img);
                        canvas.renderAll();
                }); 
            }else{
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group.item(1).setElement(img);
                        canvas.renderAll();
                }); 
            }
            canvas.calcOffset();  
        }else{
            if(sendfront=='top'){
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group1.item(0).setElement(img);
                        canvas1.renderAll();
                });         
            }else{
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group1.item(1).setElement(img);
                        canvas1.renderAll();
                }); 
            }
            canvas1.calcOffset();       
        }

    }


})();
```

Comment: What does `$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src` do..?

Comment: to change image url in canvas

Comment: What do you expect the above statement to do..? are you trying to get the `<image>` inside the dragged element..?

Comment: yeah i am trying to raplace image on canvas with new one

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you're accessing the the dragged element inside drop handler from a variable that you're setting in draggables start event, which in turn you're setting back to `null` in it's stop handler.

You don't need to do this, you can access the dropped elements from the drop event callbacks arguments. Also, you don't need to change the CSS of droppable from the `start`, `stop` callbacks of draggable, you can use the `activate` and `deactivate` options of droppable itself.

The code for your draggable - droppable interaction should be something along the following lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Define drag and drop zones */
    var $drop = $('#canvas-drop-area,#canvas-drop-area1'),
        $gallery = $('td > #image-list li'),
        $draggedImage=null;

    /* Define the draggable properties */
    $gallery.draggable({
       helper: 'clone',
       start: function (e) {
         $drop.css('display','block')
        },
       stop: function () {
         $(this).find('img').css({
           /* 'opacity': 0.4 */
         });
        },
        revert: true
    });

    /* Define the events for droppable properties */
    $drop.droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var image = ui.draggable.find("img").get(0);
            img_to_canvas(image, image.alt,$(event.target).is("#canvas-drop-area")?1:2);
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        },
        deactivate: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').css("display","none");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: yeah but why this issue occurs mainly in mobile browser ??

Comment: @mour Maybe the order of execution of `drop` and `stop` callbacks are different in mobile browser..? If you access the droppables from the callbacks argument then you don't have to worry about such issues... that is why jQuery ui gives that argument...

Comment: what changes did u made ??

Comment: @mour I'm not using a variable `$draggedImage` and setting it's value in draggables `start`  and `stop` to track the draggable, instead accessing it via `ui.draggable` in `drop` callback...

Comment: i am able to see same issue in chrome when i drag it fast what could be issue please help